# C# build fails with invalid token text at root level of document

Tags: c#, xml, build, config

I have a C# Windows Forms project that has a text file name db.config that contains a connection string like:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLSRV;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=sa;Password=********;
```

The properties of the files are:

- Build action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
- Custom Tool: -
- Custom Tool Namespace: -
- File Name: `db.config`
- Full Path: `c:\path\to\solution\Config\db.config`

When I am building the solution I get these two errors:

1. Invalid token 'Text' at root level of document.
2. XML document must contain a root level element

Any idea how on how to fix the build ?

Comment: Please add all db.config file

Comment: @Basil Kosovan I already have posted the exact full contents of the db.config file. There is nothing else in that file.

Comment: Looks like you have missed XML tags: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> ....

Comment: @Basil Sure, but is it mandatory to have it as an xml file ? When I add files to the project I see two different options, one for XML and another for Text file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude a `.config` file from the build. Just add to `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CSFile Include="*.cs" Exclude="App1.config"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

See link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2019

But I recommend using XML tags.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know if this is different, but I did this: `<ItemGroup><CSFile Remove="App1.config"/></ItemGroup>`. I'd love to know if that has the same effect if all I care about is avoiding the error the OP had.

Comment: Try to build your project with “Include” and without and check if you will have different dlls